# Lucene "not in" or "except" query

Tags: lucene

(lucene on sitecore 8.2)

I have a tabbed search results page with 5 tabs:

- people
- insights
- news
- services
- other

The "other" tab should display results that do not appear in the first four queries. I was going to try to iterate through and track all the Guids that are returned in the first four queries and then use that to have a exclude in the "other" tab query but not sure how performance would be or if there is a better way.

The first four queries I am only getting the hits and then using paging to take the first 10 - if I have to iterate through all hits and add the guids to an array - I thought that might be slower and the wrong way to go but not sure how else to do it.

Thoughts?

Comment: How are your first 4 queries done? Is this based on a template or is it more complex?

Comment: You probably need to look at a faceted query

Comment: If for some reason faceted query is not an option for you, you may try using something like (pseudocode used): `otherExpression = otherExpression.And(!peopleExpression).And(!insightsExpression).And(!newsExpression).And(!servicesExpression)`. It really depends on your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I will see if I can do something similar to Marek's suggestion. The faceted query won't work because each tab is a separate query with the author able to specify the starting location in the content tree as well as what templates to include.